# How does the Android Home Screen Launcher restore Tasks?

Tags: android, android-intent

How does Android determine what Activity/Task to restore when a user opens an app by clicking on the Home Screen Launcher?  I've run into a problem when launching an app first from the Package installer, and then from the Home Screen Launcher.

Steps:

1. Using the Package installer, install an app from an APK.
2. When installed, open the app from the Package installer.
3. Press the Home button
4. From the Home Screen, click the app icon

Problem:

The MainActivity appears on the stack **twice**. Anyone using the app would need to press the back button twice to exit. I've been able to successfully reproduce this using the New Project wizard in Android Studio with the following changes: Min SDK=14, Target SDK=17, Compile SDK=17).

Using dumpsys (adb shell dumpsys activity), I recorded the stack after the Package installer was run, and again when launching the app from the Home Screen Launcher.

After clicking "Open" from the Package installer:

```
Task id #99
      TaskRecord{424f0e10 #99 A=com.example U=0 sz=1}
      Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.example cmp=com.example/.MainActivity }
        Hist #0: ActivityRecord{4231c6e8 u0 com.example/.MainActivity t99}
          Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.example cmp=com.example/.MainActivity }
          ProcessRecord{42458650 16816:com.example/u0a294}
```

After pressing the Home button, then launching the app from the Home Screen Launcher:

```
Task id #99
  TaskRecord{424f0e10 #99 A=com.example U=0 sz=2}
  Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.example cmp=com.example/.MainActivity }
    Hist #1: ActivityRecord{431e05b8 u0 com.example/.MainActivity t99}
      Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10600000 cmp=com.example/.MainActivity }
      ProcessRecord{42458650 16816:com.example/u0a294}
    Hist #0: ActivityRecord{4231c6e8 u0 com.example/.MainActivity t99}
      Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.example cmp=com.example/.MainActivity }
      ProcessRecord{42458650 16816:com.example/u0a294}
```

It is clear that the Home Screen Launcher does restore the existing MainActivity when launched from the Home Screen.  *This was my original assumption.*  I thought that the Home Screen Launcher would detect the existing activity and just restore that task.

I've tested this on both Android 4.0.4 (Samsung Galaxy GT-N7000) and Android 4.4.2 (HTC One) and see the same results.

Any help with a solution or workaround for this problem would be appreciated, as well as any articles/documentation that describes this Android behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not alone.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if ((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) != 0) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

See http://gosyujin.github.io/2013/08/04/android-install-intent which write in Japanese.
It's works for me.